# Not able to establish Oracle SQL session from within a BASH script

Tags: sql, bash, sqlplus, oracle12c

```
#!/bin/bash
#Oracle DB Info for NEXT
HOST="1.2.3.4"
PORT="5678"
SERVICE="MYDB"
DB_USER=$(whoami)
DB_PASS=$(base64 -d ~/.passwd)
DB_SCHEMA="my_db"

#Section for all of our functions.
function SQLConnection(){
sqlplus "$DB_USER"/"$DB_PASS"@"$HOST":"$PORT"/"$SERVICE"
}

function Connected(){
SQLConnection <<EOF
select sys_context('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') from dual;
EOF
}

function GetJMS(){
SQLConnection <<EOF
set echo on timing on lines 200 pages 100
select pd.destination from ${DB_SCHEMA}.pd_notification pd where pd.org_id = '$ORGID';
EOF
}
TODAY=$(date +"%A %B %d, %Y")
read -r -p $'\n\nWhat is the ORG ID? ' ORGID
read -r -p $'\n\nWhat is the REMOTE QUEUE MANAGER NAME? ' RQM
read -r -p $'\n\nWhat is the IP address of the REMOTE QUEUE MANAGER? ' CONN
read -r -p $'\n\nWhat is the PORT of the REMOTE QUEUE MANAGER? ' PORT
echo -en "* $(whoami)\n* $TODAY\n* MQ Setup $ORGID\n\nDEFINE +\n\tCHANNEL('$RQM.LQML') +\n\tCHLTYPE(SDR) +\n\tCONNAME('$CONN($PORT)') +\n\tXMITQ('BUF.2.$ORGID.XMQ')\n\tCHAUTH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)\n\nDEFINE +\n\tCHANNEL('LQML.$RQM') +\n\tCHLTYPE(RCVR) +\n\tTRPTYPE(TCP)\n\nDEFINE +\n\tQLOCAL('$RQM') +\n\tTRIGDATA('LQML.$RQM') +\n\tINITQ('SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ') +\n\tTRIGGER USAGE(XMITQ)\n\n" > ~/mqsetup.mqsc

CONNECTED=$(Connected | awk 'NR==16')
echo -en "\n\nHello From: $CONNECTED\n\n"

for JMSDESTINATION in $(GetJMS | awk 'NR>=16&&NR<=24{print $1}')
    do
        read -r -p $'\n\nWhich REMOTE QUEUE NAME matches with this ${JMSDESTINATION}?' RNAME
        QDESC=$(echo "$JMSDESTINATION" | tr '.' ' ' | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]')
        echo -en "\n\nDEFINE +\n\tQR($JMSDESTINATION) +\n\t\tREPLACE DESCR('$ORGID $QDESC Queue') +\n\t\tREPLACE MAXDEPTH(5000) +\n\t\tXMITQ('BUF.2.$ORGID.XMQ') +\n\t\tRNAME('$RNAME') +\n\t\tRQMNAME('$RQM')" >> ~/mqsetup.mqsc
    done
```

Here is the script I've built, hoping to automate the setup of IBM MQ Queues and Channels.  My problem is that outside this script, I can establish an SQL Session without an issue, directly from the shell, provided I input the variables seen in the script.  I can call the functions and everything returns just as I'd hope it would. When I run the exact same things from within the script, I get timeout errors ... the "Hello From" is blank, which tells me there is no DB connection.

I'm totally stumped as to why it all works great from outside the script, but inside it times out.

I appreciate the eyes and the help!

Comment: The connection part seems to work OK; what do you see if you just call Connected? Where do you see the timeout errors? (Even with a connection, your awk pattern doesn't show anything for me, so you might want to do some debugging around that?)

Comment: Don't you need to escape the $ sign  in this line:  select pd.destination from ${DB_SCHEMA}.pd_notification pd where pd.org_id = '$ORGID';

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, assuming I've loaded the variables and functions into the shell directly, I can call the function "Connected" and I get an immediate output of SQLPlus headers, the db-server hostname, and all the exiting credits.  I use AWK to trim that down to just the hostname.  When I execute the script and it loads everything into its session, the script freezes like its trying to establish a db connection, but it fails because the echo statement I put in as a verification fails by printing "Hello From:             "   (blank where the hostname would be).

Comment: @BobC , I do not need to escape the $ because unlike in an SSH Tunnel, I am wanting that to expand _before_ it is submitted (whereas if I escaped it, it would run in the subshell) ... at least that's my understanding ... and its worked fine in several other scripts I've written that interact with the SQLPlus DB. (which is why this is so maddening, I have it working fine in other scripts!).

Comment: If connecting works why do you think it's timing out? The awk gives a blank entry for me, unless I change it to `NR==15`, but that's probably down to different options being reported in the banner. Personally I'd use the `-s` flag and probably `-l` too; and include `set pages 0 feedback off` - so the output is *just* the server anyway...

Comment: I was just about to suggest -s -l on sqlplus too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwritng a variable value. You have this at the top of the script:

```
PORT="5678"
```

but then later on you do:

```
read -r -p $'\n\nWhat is the PORT of the REMOTE QUEUE MANAGER? ' PORT
```

which overwrites your 5678 value with whatever is entered there. That port may not be listening on the DB server at all, or may be doing something else, or if you don't enter a value it'll default to port 1521 when you connect. But either way the connection is going to fail, either quickly or slowly depending on the port state (e.g. slower maybe if a firewall blocks it).

If you test the connection by adding a `Connected` call before the `read` calls (as I initially did) then it seems to be working fine; but the connections after the reads don't work because port value it tries to connect to is now wrong.

Use a different name for the two variables, e.g. `RQ_PORT` for the second one - both in its `read` command and the subsequent creation of the `~/mqsetup.mqsc` file.

You may also find it useful to add the `-l` flag to your SQL*Plus call so that if the connection fails for some reason it won't re-prompt for credentials, which in some circumstances can make the script appear to hang until you hit enter a few times.

---

Not directly relevant to the problem, but when automating anything like this I usually also use the `-s` flag to suppress the banners (which can vary between environments); and if you're only interested in capturing query output I'd usually set headings and/or pagination off, and feedback off, and generally set SQL*Plus up to generate as little noise as possible - it makes parsing out the interesting bits easier.

Comment: This was exactly right!  Geez, I can't believe I looked right past that!  Thanks so much for catching that.  Also, didn't know about the options "-S" and "-L" ... those will help a ton.  Thanks!